# How to format the output for an bibliographic entry?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, line-breaking

I would like my References to be formatted as the following:

```
Author(s)
Title 
Journal ref, or publishers information
Doi or/& ISBN
Year
```

How could I do that? I am using BibTeX with natbib. Sorry if this is already answered, but all I could find was formatting between two reference entries (while I am asking for formatting a single entry). Thanks and regards.

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want line breaks, or double line breaks, between the fields? If not, what kind of punctuation should be inserted between fields? How should authors’ names be formatted? Full or truncated given names, with commas or some other characters between authors?

Comment: A single line break between the fields. For authors, I would prefer APS style, that is A. Smith, B. C. Johnson, and R. G. Horn. Separation between fields would be comma, except the last one which should be a period.

Comment: Your follow-up comment suggests that you wish to adhere to APS style. I therefore think you should familiarize yourself -- if you haven't already done -- with the `biblatex` package and the `biblatex-phys` style. (Until a few years ago, the learning curve of biblatex was very steep -- and never seemed to flatten. Fortunately, biblatex has become much more user-friendly in the meantime.) biblatex's output is far more programmable than that of bibtex/natbib. In particular, with `biblatex` it takes probably just a single instruction to switch to line breaks between fields. (continued)

Comment: (continued) May I therefore suggest if you can manage the switch from natbib/bibtex to biblatex/biber and then, if necessary, post a new query on this site to ask how to get the newlines working? Thanks.